# Redirecting users to log in page but still using their search query

Tags: php, mysql, get

I am trying to build a demo booking system with php and mysql. First users searches available seats from the different tables. When they search i send their search data in the url with GET method and check from the db against their searches. If a particular day and seat is found i show them total price and set a "Next" button. see it here: [search for booking](http://postimg.org/image/kwo9d3pnr/).

From this point i want to check the user who searched is logged in or not when he clicks on the "Next" button. if he is not logged in i want to redirect him to the login page and after successful log in i want him to proceed for the check out. But as his searches are sent through the url and he lands on the log in page , i lose his data from the url(because its a different page). How do i still get those search data when he is on log in page so after log in i can store those data in the users booking table? What could be the best solution?

Comment: You shall check whether the session is set or not. If yes you shall direct him accordingly. You need help in it ?

Comment: Either use sessions to store the search or attach the url parameters when redirecting to the login page.

Comment: Thank you guys. I am a beginner. But have great curiosity in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try something like this it will work :**

```
<?php
if($userid == '')
{
?>
<a href="login.php?search=<?php echo $search; ?>&price=<?php echo $price; ?>">NEXT</a>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<a href="checkout.php">NEXT</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Here, `$userid` is used for checking that user is logged in or not. It can be a `session` or `cookie` variable.

Now, If user is not `logged in` you redirect to the user to `login.php` page with the `parameters`($search,$price and so on..) you want to `store` in `db`.

**login.php :**

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
$price = $_GET['price'];
so on..
```

Here, in `login.php` you get all the parameters you passed in url using `$_GET`.
and if login is successfull. then you save these parameters into `database`.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: This won't work the way you want it. You're not echoing the links so the first one will just be a link to `login.php?search=$search&price=$price` without $search and $price being replaced.

Comment: @IkoTikashi, Its a common sense dear..obviously here `$search` and `$price` having values getting from back page url.

Comment: First up, I'm not your "dear". Secondly, even if `$search` and `$price` had values, you'd still be pointing to `login.php?search=$search&price=$price`, since you're not echoing out the links but just outputting them in HTML. Which makes your code for `login.php` obsolete, since `$_GET['search']` is not set.

Comment: Not the nicest code, but here we go, at least functional now.